# <Details> element expands upwards when container is scrolled to bottom

Tags: html, css, layout

Ordinarily, when a `<details>` element is opened, the `> details` changes to `v details`, and the expanded content appears below.

But if its container is scrolled as far down as it goes, the content expands up, pushing up the initial `> details` up with it (and `<summary>`, if included.)

If there is a lot of content in the details, the top/summary line may be pushed up off screen altogether.

**Is it possible to force the <details> content to expand downward, even if its container is scrolled to the bottom?**

(Solutions are ideally HTML/CSS; I could probably force it through JS, but I just feel like there's something basic I'm missing.)

Comment: Can provide a minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: MRE is make a <details> with long content, scroll to bottom of screen or container, open <details>, observe opening up instead of down.

Comment: For me (firefox 88.0.1) the behavour is even more more inconsistent than you describe. I can't figure out what this is a function of. Whatever it's going by, there's no way it's what users expect.